# Android, root, whitelist

Tags: java, android, root, whitelist

How can I create whitelist with root-granted apps? Other apps must be denied whithout any prompt.

I'm looking for existing solution or some advice how to write app with this features.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [Superuser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su&hl=en) on the market. This app can manage what apps have root access to the device.

Comment: No, I need app without asking user to allow `su` access.

Answer (score 0):

use
[Download Magisk Manager](https://magiskmanager.com/)

**solutions 1**

1. its have feature for app selection for pregranted and for other apps

[image]

**solutions 2**

1. first manually grant permission from Magisk app
2. set default Aotometic Response -> Deny

[image]

be free to ask for more help :)